# Magento 2 admin page redirecting to homepage

Tags: magento2, admin-panel, home-page

My admin URL redirecting to homepage, I have did lot of efforts to fix admin login link but still it migrating to homepage,

my website link https://www.muzikhausberlin.de/index.php
my admin link https://www.muzikhausberlin.de/admin

Comment: delete the contents of the following directories => var/cache and 
/var/session

Comment: For sure check also do you use correct admin url by typing: php bin/magento info:adminuri

Comment: there is no session folder inside var..  cache cleared

Comment: https://snag.gy/1Jhxcm.jpg

Comment: Have You Tried Changing in `core_config_data` Table?

Comment: yes i tried to change secure and non secure url in core_config_data

Comment: @AadiiMughal I know you would have tried following already. Please do this again for me ;)
rm -rf var/cache var/session generated;
bin/magento setup:upgrade --keep-generated
php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:di:compile

Since, you have already tried changing in core_config_data. I would like you to check your .htaccess and server configuration.
Also, make sure your root directory has appropriate permissions. I think it's more like a server configuration or permission issue than magento issue. And please check if rewrite is enabled for server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after hard hurdle i got it fixed. i replace htaccess file with this code and working perfect

```
    ############################################
## uncomment the line below to enable developer mode

#   SetEnv MAGE_MODE developer

############################################
## uncomment these lines for CGI mode
## make sure to specify the correct cgi php binary file name
## it might be /cgi-bin/php-cgi

#    Action php5-cgi /cgi-bin/php5-cgi
#    AddHandler php5-cgi .php

############################################
## GoDaddy specific options

#   Options -MultiViews

## you might also need to add this line to php.ini
##     cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
## if it still doesn't work, rename php.ini to php5.ini

############################################
## this line is specific for 1and1 hosting

    #AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
    #AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php

############################################
## default index file

    DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_php5.c>

############################################
## adjust memory limit

    php_value memory_limit 768M
    php_value max_execution_time 18000

############################################
## disable automatic session start
## before autoload was initialized

    php_flag session.auto_start off

############################################
## enable resulting html compression

    #php_flag zlib.output_compression on

###########################################
## disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_security.c>
###########################################
## disable POST processing to not break multiple image upload

    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

############################################
## enable apache served files compression
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

    # Insert filter on all content
    ###SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    # Insert filter on selected content types only
    #AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript

    # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

    # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

    # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
    #BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

    # Don't compress images
    #SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

    # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
    #Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

############################################
## make HTTPS env vars available for CGI mode

    SSLOptions StdEnvVars

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

    #RewriteBase /magento/

############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
    RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]

############################################
## redirect for mobile user agents

    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobiledirectoryhere/.*$
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobiledirectoryhere/ [L,R=302]

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>


############################################
## Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides
## If you still have problems, use the second line instead

    AddDefaultCharset Off
    #AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/html A0
    ExpiresByType text/plain A0

</IfModule>

###########################################
## Deny access to root files to hide sensitive application information
    RedirectMatch 404 /\.git

    <Files composer.json>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files composer.lock>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files .gitignore>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files .htaccess>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files .htaccess.sample>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files .php_cs>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files .travis.yml>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files CHANGELOG.md>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files CONTRIBUTING.md>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files CONTRIBUTOR_LICENSE_AGREEMENT.html>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files COPYING.txt>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files Gruntfile.js>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files LICENSE.txt>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files LICENSE_AFL.txt>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files nginx.conf.sample>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files package.json>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files php.ini.sample>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
    <Files README.md>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>

################################
## If running in cluster environment, uncomment this
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags

    #FileETag none
```

Answer (score -1):

> You can Change in **env.php** file

```
'backend' => [
        'frontName' => 'admin'
    ]
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: already did.. but not working

Comment: did you try after `cache:flush` ?