# Magento Admin redirects to homepage after login

Tags: login, redirect

i configured the magento backend. But now it redirects me to the homepage after successful login. When i type the backend url again, it also directly puts me to the front end.
I did clear all cache, tried different browsers etc.

Can anyone help?

Comment: So i got it fixed that it will return me to homepage, but it seems like as it uses the old backend url. After login it redirects me to xxx.domain.eu/admin/index.php/backend instead of xxx.domain.eu/index.php/backend - I recently changed the url to xxx.domain.eu/admin, but that didn't work well, so i changed it back do xxx.domain.eu/ . but it seems like it uses the old url...

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/281977/magento-2-admin-page-redirecting-to-homepage check this...